# Find files which names start the same

Tags: regex, file, unix

I have a bunch of files named with the following pattern:

```
NAME_TYPE.viz
```

and I'm interested in finding all "NAME" for which there is multiple files. For example suppose the file list is

```
A_type1.viz
A_type2.viz
1_type1.viz
1A_grop.viz
1A_grop2.viz
```

I would like to get "A" and "1A".

Edit: it seems I have not been clear enough.

1. I don't know what NAMES are, so I cannot search for a specific pattern.
2. I am only interested to output a list of `NAME` for which there exist at least two files matching the pattern `NAME*.viz` and not all `NAME` such there is only one `NAME_*.viz`.

Thanks in advance.

Edit2: Thanks to @hek2mgl I achieved to reach a solution which is

`find /my/path/ -type f -name '*_*.viz' | sed -r 's/([^_]+).*/\1/' | sort | uniq -d`

Comment: why you want to match only the above two?

Comment: I made a mistake. I edited to change that. I'd like to find all "NAME" which belong to multiple types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` and `sed`:

```
find /path/to/files type f -name '*_*.viz' | sed -r 's/([^_]+).*/\1/'
```

The command above will find files recursively meaning it will also find files in sub folders of `/path/to/files`. If you don't want that pass the argument `-maxdepth 1` to `find`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't seems to work entirely. For example it identifies CCNJ_type.viz and CCNJL_othertype.viz to a same "CCNJ" pattern.

Comment: NAMEs are different, "CCNJ" in the first case and CCNJL is the second one.

Comment: What means `identifies ... to the same pattern` ?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear enough. The command you suggest outputs "./CCNJ" and when I simply look at all files starting with "CCNJ" (ls CCNJ*, since there are no subfolders) I have two of them which are CCNJ_chr10.viz and CCNJL_chr5.viz. Thanks again.

Comment: Can't reproduce that. Having both the files you named, I can't the following output `CCNJ`, `CCNJL`..

Comment: You're right both CCNJ & CCNJL appear. I assumed the output was alphabetically ordered which is not the case, my bad. But in fact I don't want either of them to appear in the output. I've edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: You would need to pipe results to `... | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1>1{print $2} | uniq`

Answer (score 0):

`find`-only solution that finds all `.viz` files in `/your/path/` that start with `NAME_`:

```
find /your/path/ -type f -name "NAME_*.viz"
```

Using regex:

```
find /your/path/ -type f -regex ".*/NAME_.*.viz"
```

So if you want to find all `.viz` files that start with `A_` or `1A_`:

```
find /your/path/ -type f -regex ".*/1?A_.*.viz"
```

Comment: I don't know the "NAME" it can be anything combination of letter+number+dash basically. What you propose will only output all files matching the pattern "NAME_*.viz" or "1?A_*.viz"?  This is not really my issue.

Comment: Of course you have to specify some regex for your `NAME` pattern. If my answer doesn't help you, please explain your issue in more detail.

Comment: I already did edit my question. However I reached a solution based on what @hek2mgl proposed. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is complicated enough that I would just use python. I tested this, it should work for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import os
import re

names = set({})
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/your/path"):
    if len(files) > 0:
        for f in files:
            m = re.search('^([^_]+)_.*$', f)
            if m:
                names.add(m.group(1))
for name in names:
    print(name)
```

place the code in `foo.py` and run `python foo.py`, your system should have a python interpreter installed, most do :D